# How do you use Toplevel() to detach/open a new graph window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

I'm a total newbie to programming in Tkinter and could use some help while I figure out how Tkinter deals with classes, functions and so on.

I'm trying to make a way to "detach" the graph window by a button in the graphical window. I need to be able to open the class, GraphPage_cpu -> see the page with the plots and then press the "test" button and have it open a new window with the cpu measure plot.

**Also I have to give a huge credit to the user, "j_4321". He really helped me a lot with figuring out how to plot cpu measures!**

This is the main function for trying to detach (or "re-open" the graphical in a new window):

```
def detach_graph(self):
        self.detach_graph = Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.app = GraphPage_cpu(self.detach_graph)
```

Error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-12-f73649f067eb>", line 124, in new_window
    self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.parent)
AttributeError: 'GraphPage_cpu' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Toplevel
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo, showwarning, askquestion
from tkinter import OptionMenu
from tkinter import StringVar

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from psutil import cpu_percent
from psutil import virtual_memory
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import sklearn.cluster as cluster
import scipy.spatial.distance as sdist
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

RANDOM_STATE = 42 #used to help randomly select the data points
low_memory=False
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
style.use("ggplot")

f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)


class Analyticsapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="iconimage_kmeans.ico") #Icon for program
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Advanched analytics")
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.frames = {} 
        
        for F in (StartPage, GraphPage_cpu):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=
                         "Advanched analytics", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="CPU Usage", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(GraphPage_cpu))
        button3.pack(fill='x')

class GraphPage_cpu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, nb_points=360):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="CPU Usage", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10, side='top')

        # matplotlib figure
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # format the x-axis to show the time
        myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
        # initial x and y data
        dateTimeObj = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=-nb_points)
        self.x_data = [dateTimeObj + timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(nb_points)]
        self.y_data = [0 for i in range(nb_points)]
        # create the plot
        self.plot = self.ax.plot(self.x_data, self.y_data, label='CPU')[0]
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.x_data[0], self.x_data[-1])

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, self)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack(side='bottom')
        
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Test",
                             command=self.new_window)
        button2.pack(side='bottom')
        
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.animate_cpu()
        
    def detach_graph(self):
        self.detach_graph = Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.app = GraphPage_cpu(self.detach_graph)

    def animate_cpu(self):
        # append new data point to the x and y data
        self.x_data.append(datetime.now())
        self.y_data.append(cpu_percent())
        # remove oldest data point
        self.x_data = self.x_data[1:]
        self.y_data = self.y_data[1:]
        #  update plot data
        self.plot.set_xdata(self.x_data)
        self.plot.set_ydata(self.y_data)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.x_data[0], self.x_data[-1])
        self.canvas.draw_idle()  # redraw plot
        self.after(1000, self.animate_cpu)  # repeat after 1s
        
app = Analyticsapp()
app.geometry('500x400')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add a `self.parent = parent` to `GraphPage_cpu.__init__()` so the attribute exists.

Comment: When adding "self.parent = parent" under "tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)" under "GraphPage_cpu.__init__()" I get the error; "TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'controller'"

Comment: Adding `self.parent = parent` near the very beginning of  the`GraphPage_cpu.__init__()` method would not cause that error — don't change the `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)` call (or anything else).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue (cannot run due to dependencies),
you need to get the parent of some widget.
tkinter uses 'master', not 'parent', so try:

```
self.newWindow = Toplevel(self.master)
```